# Create a Counter within a For-Loop?

Tags: php, javascript, for-loop, counter

I am a novice programmer and apologize upfront for the complicated question.

I am trying to create a lexical decision task for experimental research, in which respondents must decide if a series of letters presented on the screen make a "word" or "not a word". Everything works reasonably well except for the bit where I want to randomly select a word (category A) or nonword (category B) for each of 80 trials from a separate input file (input.txt). The randomization works, but some elements from each list (category A or B) are skipped because I have used "round.catIndex = j;" where "j" is a loop for each successive trial. Because some trials randomly select from Category A and other from Category B, "j" does not move successively down the list for each category. Instead, elements from the Category A list may be selected from something like 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, and so on (it varies each time because of the randomization).

To make a long story short(!), how do I create a counter that will work within the for-loop for each trial, so that every word and nonword from Category A and B, respectively, will be used for the lexical decision task? Everything I have tried thus far does not work properly or breaks the javascript entirely.

Below is my code snippet and the full code is available at http://50.17.194.59/LDT/trunk/LDT.js. Also, the full lexical decision task can be accessed at http://50.17.194.59/LDT/trunk/LDT.php. Thanks!

```
    function initRounds()
    {
        numlst = [];
        for (var k = 0; k<numrounds; k++)
            {
                if (k % 2 == 0) numlst[k] = 0;
                else numlst[k] = 1;
            }
        numlst.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})

        for (var j = 0; j<numrounds; j++)
            {       
                var round = new LDTround();
                if (numlst[j] == 0)
                    {
                        round.category = input.catA.datalabel;
                    }
                else if (numlst[j] == 1)
                    {
                        round.category = input.catB.datalabel;
                    }

                // pick a category & stimulus
                    if (round.category == input.catA.datalabel) 
                        {
                            round.itemtype = input.catA.itemtype;
                            round.correct = 1;
                            round.catIndex = j;
                        }
                    else if (round.category == input.catB.datalabel)
                        { 
                            round.itemtype = input.catB.itemtype;
                            round.correct = 2;
                            round.catIndex = j;   
                        }       
                    roundArray[i].push(round);
                }
        return roundArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to declare multiple variables and execute multiple statements within a single `for` loop.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
for(var CatAIndex = 0, CatBIndex = 0; CatAIndex+CatBIndex < numrounds; incrementA ? CatAIndex++ : CatBIndex++) {
    // Insert your code here
}
```

I chose those verbose variable names to make it more clear. You'd have two separate indices for category A and B, and you compare the sum of the two versus the number of rounds you want to run. Then inside of your `for` loop somewhere, you set the boolean `incrementA` to either `true` or `false` to indicate which one to increment.

That roughly matches what you're asking for, but I think what you'd prefer is to use a combination of `Math.random`, `<array>.splice` and `<array>.length` to get a random word/nonword from each list, rather than producing a predictable order for selection. Then you don't even *care* what the indices are for the two categories and you can go back to a simple `for(var i = 0; i < numrounds; i++)` type of loop.

If the latter is what you really want, leave a comment on this answer and I'll update it with another example.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I'm assuming that the actual number and order of words and non-words is not really defined by your test, because otherwise a user could pick up the word/non-word pattern and Christmas Tree the test. I'm also assuming that you have two array of words and non-words called `catA` and `catB` in the global scope. Below is a function that will do the following:

1. Randomly pick a word or non-word.
2. Never repeat a word or non-word pick (meaning that technically it becomes more deterministic the closer to the end of the list you are.
3. Until all words are exhausted, at which point it will automatically "refresh" its list from the `catA` and `catB` arrays. (So you can set `numrounds` to `+inf` if you like.)

.

```
var pickAWord = (function outerScope() {
    var allWords = [];
    return function innerClosure() {
        if(allWords.length == 0) {
            allWords = [].concat(catA, catB);
        }
        return allWords.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*allWords.length), 1)[0];
    };
})();
```

The function is using the functional programming concept of closures to create a persisted "global-like" variable, `allWords` that only it can see. The function automatically refreshes the array with all of the words when the length of the array reaches zero (like it is from the start) using the globals `catA` and `catB`. To use it in a for loop, simply:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numrounds; i++) {
    var wordToUse = pickAWord();
    // Do something
}
```

If you need to guarantee that an equal number of `catA` and `catB` words are used, the `outerScope` function will need to keep track of three variables: copies of `catA` and `catB`, and an array the same size as `numrounds`, half of which are `true` and half `false`. `splice` randomly from this true/false array, and then splice randomly from either `catA` or `catB` depending on whether it's `true` or `false`. Then you function will need code to "refresh" all of these closure variables, but it would be essentially the same as how the function is written above.

Sorry if the function is a bit complex, but you see how easy it is to use, right? :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed comments. As you guessed, your latter suggestion is more along the lines of what I would like to do (I just had no idea how to do it!). If you could post an example, I should (hopefully) be able to figure out how to add that to my program. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, I had gone to bed when you answered last night. I've edited the question with how I'd solve it.

Comment: Ahh, that's really cool. Your explanation helps me understand how to address this issue (finally!). I'll let you know how it goes...

Comment: Hey, I made a mistake in the ``pickAWord`` function (and it wasn't being formatted by the markdown properly, so I made it more readable, too). Just posting this comment so it'll show up in your 'inbox'. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've finally gotten my LDT task to work! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem.  Here is my answer based on this possible interpretations of your question:

You would like to use a for loop to process all of the Category A elements (and similarly another loop to process all Category B elements).  In this case you can loop through the roundArray and treat the elements according to their category:

```
for (var j=0; j < numrounds, j++) {
  var round = roundArray[i][j];
  // you might want to use a test better suiting the context if input is not available at the
  // time when round is processed, I am using this based on the code sample you provided
  if (round.itemType == input.catA.itemType) {
    // process round as Category A
    // use numlst[round.catIndex] to access the corresponding element in numlst
  } else {
    // process round as Category B
    // use numlst[round.catIndex] to access the corresponding element in numlst
  }
}
// alternatively, you can break the loop into two and process only Category A in one instance
// and only Category B in the other (the if branch corresponding to the other category would be
// empty)
```

If this is not your intention, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using David Ellis' help since he replied first. Cheers!